# How can i understand what template is the c# project based on

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates

I got the c# project and unfortunately there is no any connection with creator. 
Is any chance understand what template was used for this project ? 
.
Project was created in VS 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're referring to specifically but you can check a few things by going to `Project > PROJNAME Properties > Application` in VS.

This menu will show you the Target Framework and Output Type for the application and also allow you to change the aforementioned options.

If you're not using VS, most editors have a similar menu option or you can just look at the `PROJNAME.csproj` file. It'll tell you the same things as the menu I mentioned earlier.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it's helped thanks but still have question.
In project used: MVC, Entity Framework, jquery, easyui, pure, angular, bootstrap, ML.net etc...
so i have mishmash and i want to understand what's template was first?
Take a look in picture. Which one has been used?    https://img.techpowerup.org/200419/222.jpg

Comment: @AlGraf Ah. I see what you're after now. You can see via the Output Type of the application. Console Application will be output as Console Applications, Libraries will be Output as Class Library, etc Though this alone won't always tell you exactly what it is.

EDIT: After re-reading. If its referencing MVC, then the application is likely an ASP.Net MVC application. `Web > ASP.Net Core Application` or `Web > ASP.Net Web Application`

Comment: yes. looks likes like this is it. I thought  project have property like BasedON = WindowsFormsApp but it's acceptable too. Thanx.